# Token-finding function

Tags: c++, parsing

I want to make sure `find_value_from_key()` is safe and efficient.  My constraints are language C++, use of standard library ok, but cannot use Boost or any new C++11 features.

Can anyone offer any comments/criticisms/feedback on my implementation of the function here?  Any flaws in my test cases would also be interesting to hear.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;


bool find_value_from_key(const string& source, const string& key, string& value, const string& EndOfValueMarker) {
   bool ret = false;
   size_t pos_start = source.find(key);
   if(pos_start != string::npos) {
      size_t pos_end = source.find_first_of(EndOfValueMarker, pos_start+key.length());
      if(pos_end == string::npos && source.length() > pos_start+key.length())
         pos_end = source.length();

      if(pos_end != string::npos) {
         value = source.substr(pos_start+key.length(), pos_end-pos_start-key.length());
         ret = true;
      }
   }
   return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   //test strings to exercise find_value_from_key function 
   const char* test_strings[] = {
      "key1 = value1", 
      "   key1 = value1   ", 
      "key1 = value1,key2 = value2 ,key3 = value3",
      "_key1 = value1 ,key2 = value2 ,Gkey3 = value3,", 
      "key1 = value1,key2 =  value2 ,key3 = value3 x", 
      "key1 = value1,key2 = value2key3 = value3\n", 
      "key1 = value1_,key2 = value2 ,key3 = value3                    ", 
      "key1 = value1$,key2 = value2 ,key3 =   value3", 
      "key1 = value1\t,key2 = value2  ,key3 = value3\t" };

   const char* keys[] = {"key1 = ", "key2 = ", "key3 = "};

   int elements = sizeof(test_strings) / sizeof(test_strings[0]);

   for(int i = 0; i < elements; ++i) {
     cout << "processing: " << test_strings[i] << endl;
     string value;
     if(find_value_from_key(test_strings[0], keys[0], value, ", \t\n"))
        cout << value << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the ultimate goal with this code. Are you being provided with comma separated key value pairs? Are you going to be doing repeated searches of this string of data? Will your keys always be unique in the string you are given? This implementation is case sensitive, do you need to worry about case insensitive key lookup?

Answer (score 5):

### find_value_from_key

The core method `find_value_from_key` looks functional for the limited specification you have given. I am not a great fan of the specification though, I think the function should try to be a bit smarter about identifying values in the input strings. The two items I find most concerning are:

- It will successfully find `key1 =`  and `value1` in `"ThisIsSubkey1 = value1"`
- it does not successfully find `value1` in `"key1 =  value1"` (note two spaces after `=`)

These are both items related to the context-naive usage of the `find(...)` method.

Still, as far as the specification goes, your code looks like it does the job.

There is one improvement that can/should be done to make it more readable. You reuse the value `pos_start+key.length()` four times. Performance-wise this may be sorted out by a compiler, but it does not help the readability at all...

I would prefer the function written as:

```
bool find_value_from_key(const string& source, const string& key, string& value, const string& endmarkers) {
   bool ret = false;
   size_t key_start = source.find(key);
   size_t val_start = key_start + key.length();
   if(key_start != string::npos) {
      size_t val_end = source.find_first_of(endmarkers, val_start);
      if(val_end == string::npos && source.length() > val_start)
         val_end = source.length();

      if(val_end != string::npos) {
         value = source.substr(val_start, val_end - val_start);
         ret = true;
      }
   }
   return ret;
}
```

Note how there is no `pos_start` variable... it was being reused for different purposes in different places. It was confusing. Renaming the variables to self-document makes the code easier to understand. The compiler will sort out any optimizations in the same ways as before.

There is one additional item in that method... why the CamelCase parameter `EndOfValueMarker`? I have renamed it `endmarkers`.

### main

The main method has a couple of issues I think must just be an artifact from testing.

You set up the loop to check each input string, but, you do not use `i` (the loop variable) as an index to the actual data you check... you have the code:

> ```
>    for(int i = 0; i < elements; ++i) {
>      cout << "processing: " << test_strings[i] << endl;
>      string value;
>      if(find_value_from_key(test_strings[0], keys[0], value, ", \t\n"))
>         cout << value << endl;
>    }
> ```

This code prints each `test_strings[i]` just fine, but the input to the function is always index `0`... so you only actually test the first input.

The second item is that you only test for key1. The other keys are not tested.

The loop code should look like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < elements; ++i) {
    cout << "processing: " << test_strings[i] << endl;
    string value;
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        if(find_value_from_key(test_strings[i], keys[k], value, ", \t\n"))
            cout << keys[k] << " -> " << value << endl;
    }
}
```

I know, it has the magic number `3` for the k loop, but at least it checks each key....

### Ideone

I have put my recommendations in to [this ideone... take it for a spin](http://ideone.com/mvsW8X)

Answer (score 4):

@rolfl has mentioned some great points, so I won't repeat those.  I'll address some C++-specific things I've found, keeping in mind that Boost and C++11 shouldn't be mentioned.

- These `using` statements:

  ```
  using std::cout;
  using std::endl;
  using std::string;
  ```

  are okay to use, but I'd still use `std::` where needed, especially if this list ends up getting longer.  But this is still better than having `using namespace std`.
- Regarding the use of `char* []`:

  For this:

  ```
  int elements = sizeof(test_strings) / sizeof(test_strings[0]);
  ```

  `elements` should be of type `std::size_t`, which is the return type of the `sizeof` operator.  You should also give it a more accurate name, such as `numberOfElements`.

  Moreover, you shouldn't be needing to do this in C++ when you have access to the standard library.  You can instead have an `std::vector` of `std::string`s instead of `char* []`.

  For instance, this is what `test_strings` would look like:

  ```
  std::vector<std::string> test_strings = { /* string 1 */, /* string n */ };
  ```

  To get the size, just use `size()`:

  ```
  std::vector<std::string>::size_type elements = test_strings.size();
  ```

  This type should also be used when incrementing through the number of `element`s.

  Instead of using `test_strings[0]` to access the first element, you can use `front()`:

  ```
  test_strings.front();
  ```

  I've also done a quick example test of all this [here](http://ideone.com/zYwDM9).